# key is not defined React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building small task. When we press button "add user" - we see a form, which has inputs inside. When we put info in inputs - we can press button "send info". And we add a new user. I use react to build it. When I add new user to Users array I create id for this user. And then I use this id. But a problem is that after I put info in form  and press button "send info" - I see in console "Inline Babel script:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: key
is not defined". Why does it happen?

```css
.user{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
}
.user-name, .user-phone, .user-address, .user-photo, .buttons{
    width: 20vw;
}
#header{
    background: goldenrod;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: 6vw;
}
#add-user-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top:2vw;
    right: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    
    class MainContainer extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state={
                Users: []
            }
        }
       
        render(){
            let usersToShow=this._getUser();
            let id;
            return(
                <div>
                    <HeaderTab/>
                    {usersToShow}
                    <Form addUser={this._addUser.bind(this)}/>
                </div>

            )
        }   
         makeid() {
             var text = "";
             var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

              for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

            return text;
        } 
         _addUser(name, phone, address){
                const user = {
                    id: this.makeid(),
                    name,
                    phone,
                    address
                }
                console.log(user.id);
                this.setState({Users: this.state.Users.concat([user])})
            }
            _getUser(){
                return (this.state.Users.map((user)=>{
                    return(
                        <User 
                              key={user.id}
                              name={user.name}
                              phone={user.phone}
                              address={user.address}/>
                    );
                })
            )
            }
         
    }  
    
    class Form extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state={
                displayModal: false
            }
        }
        
        render(){
            let form;
            let btnText;
            if (this.state.displayModal){
                form=<div id ="form">
                     <form onSubmit ={this._handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="name" ref={(input)=>this._name=input}></input>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="address" ref={(input)=>this._address=input}></input>
                        <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" ref={(input)=>this._phone=input}></input>
                        <button type="submit">Send info</button>
                     </form>
                    </div>;
                btnText= 'cansel'   
            }
            else{
                form=null;
                btnText= 'addUser' 
            }
            return(
                <div>
                    <button id="add-user-btn" onClick={this._showModal.bind(this)}>{btnText}</button>        
                    {form}
            </div>)
        }  

        _showModal(){
            this.setState(
                {displayModal: !this.state.displayModal}
            );
        }
        _handleSubmit(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            let name=this._name;
            let phone=this._phone;
            let address=this._address;
            this.props.addUser(name.value, phone.value, address.value);

        }
            
        
    } 
    
    class HeaderTab extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <header id="header">
                    <div className="user-name">Name</div>
                    <div className="user-phone">Phone</div>
                    <div className="user-address">Address</div>
                    <div className="user-photo">Photo</div>
                    <div className="buttons"></div>
                </header>
        )
        }  
    } 
    

    class User extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
            <div className="user" key={key}>
                 <div className="user-name">{name}</div>
                 <div className="user-phone">{phone}</div>
                 <div className="user-address">{address}</div>
                 <div className="user-photo"></div>
                 <div className="buttons">
                     <button className="delete">delete</button>
                     <button className="edit">edit</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
    )
}      
}

      ReactDOM.render(
        <MainContainer/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: console.log(id); <= at this point it would be user.id

Comment: Change console.log(id) => console.log(user.id)

Answer (score 1):

console.log(id); should be changed to console.log(user.id);

Comment: Yes console.log I change. But the problem is still is

Comment: Now the issue is with the key={key} in render() of user component. Try removing that.

Comment: how I can remove it? each element created by map in react need it

Comment: I meant the key from the statement in the render method of user component. <div className=“user”> is enough

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the implementation of this class:

```
class User extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
            <div className="user" key={key}>
                 <div className="user-name">{name}</div>
                 <div className="user-phone">{phone}</div>
                 <div className="user-address">{address}</div>
                 <div className="user-photo"></div>
                 <div className="buttons">
                     <button className="delete">delete</button>
                     <button className="edit">edit</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
    )
}      
}
```

The render function refers to several undefined variables.

In order for this class to execute without errors, the render function either needs to remove the references to undefined variables or provide definitions for those variables.

It's worth noting that this interpolation syntax:

```
<div>{ someVariable }</div>
```

requires `someVariable` to be a defined variable within the scope of the block.
The code inside the interpolation (i.e. `someVariable` in this case) is executed as ordinary JavaScript.

This feature allows us to write code like this:

```
<div>2 + 2 is { 2 + 2 }</div>
```

Which is rendered like this:

```
<div>2 + 2 is 4</div>
```